# Looking for a string that is not inside another string pattern

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm having a classic `if, else, endif` implementation in a proprietary language.

Given I have the string below, I want to locate the `[!--@Else--]` statement, but only the one that is **NOT** inside the `[!--@If--]...[!--@EndIf--]` block. So I want an even number of openings and closing of `if`s before matching the `else`...

---

```
Lorem ipsum
[!--@If(1=1)--]
One it is
    [!--@If(2=1)--]
        2 is not 1
    [!--@Else--]
        so do this
    [!--@EndIf--]
[!--@Else--]
1 is not 1
[!--@EndIf--]
and something else
```

---

In this example, I want to locate the second `else` - and not the first since it is inside the `if/endif` block.

I've now spend countless hours with negative and positive lookbehinds and cannot get it to work!?

Comment: There are no occurrences of `[!--@Else--]` not inside a `[!--@If--]...[!--@EndIf--]` block. Did you mean the outermost occurrence of an `[!--@Else--]`?

Comment: @Asad - yes, of course. Starting inside the outermost if/else, locate the else that are not inside the nested if/else.

Comment: which language...? regex implementation differs from language to language

Comment: Have you tried "balancing groups": http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/balancing-groups ? The later examples in this article seem useful to tackle your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Abbondanza mentioned, you will need balancing groups if you want to do this with regex. I should warn you, this is not going to be a nice solution. While .NET's regex engine is one of the few, that can handle cases like this, it is still not really the recommended approach. You are probably better off parsing your language manually, which allows you to count nesting levels much more easily.

Anyway, just to show you, why regular expressions are inappropriate for this task in productive software, here is a regex (use `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` and `RegexOptions.Singleline`) that still makes some simplifying assumptions (which I will get to later):

```
(?<=\[!--@Else--\])      # Make sure that our match begins right after an else
                         # block.
[^\[]*                   # Match as many non-[ characters as possible (the actual
                         # statement)
(?=                      # This lookahead will assert that the previous statement
                         # was a top-level Else
  (?<Depth>)             # Push one capture onto the stack "Depth" (because, if
                         # this is one of the desired "Else"s we are exactly one
                         # level deep
  (?>                    # Start a subpattern for anything that could follow and
                         # suppress backtracking (because the alternatives are
                         # mutually exclusive)
    (?<Depth>\[!--@If\([^()]*\)--\])
                         # If we encounter an If block, push a new capture onto
                         # the stack (because the nesting level rises)
  |                      # OR
    (?<-Depth>)\[!--@EndIf--\]     
                         # IF we can pop a capture from the stack, consume an 
                         # EndIf. If we cannot, the named group will fail. Hence
                         # we can only consume one EndIf more than we already
                         # encountered Ifs.
  |                      # OR
    (?!\[!--@EndIf--\]). # If this character does not mark the beginning of an
                         # EndIf, consume an arbitrary character.
  )*                     # Repeat as long as possible.
  $                      # Make sure we have reached the end of the string.
  (?(Depth)(?!))         # If there is anything left on the stack, fail, too,
                         # because there are some Ifs that were not closed, so
                         # the syntax was invalid anyway.
                         # You can leave this out if you have convinced yourself
                         # beforehand that the overall nesting syntax is correct.
)                        # End of lookahead.
```

Now this is already quite a beast, which almost no one would understand without this novel of comments.

But I mentioned simplifying assumptions. Here you go.

1. I disallow any kind of parentheses inside `If` conditions. If you want to do that, you will have to check **their** correct nesting, too. It is slightly simpler than what I did here, but it will still require building up and down a stack of parentheses.
2. The main issue is probably the actual match `[\[]]*`. Since I disallow any kind of opening parentheses, you cannot have conditional statements inside the `Else` block. Now if you want to allow this, you have to copy almost the whole thing again into the actual match, so that you know which `If`s and `EndIf`s are **inside** the `Else` and which ones come afterwards.

You see, to get a regex solution that covers 100% of all cases, you would need to make that code completely unmaintainable. That's why you should really consider, analyzing the string manually and building some kind of syntax tree. This way you get an OOP representation of your nesting structures which can easily be traversed for the specific `Else`s you want to find.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've actually got the balancing up and running now and have a solution that is "good enough". It is not bullet proof as you write is difficult.

Comment: <!--@If(?<BoolOperator>(?: Not)?)\((?<TagName>.+?)(?<Operator><contains>|<startswith>|<endswith>|[!<>=]+)(?<TestValue>.*?)\)-->(?>(?!<!--@If(?<BoolOperator>(?: Not)?)\((?<TagName>.+?)(?<Operator><contains>|<startswith>|<endswith>|[!<>=]+)(?<TestValue>.*?)\)-->|<!--@EndIf-->).|<!--@If(?<BoolOperator>(?: Not)?)\((?<TagName>.+?)(?<Operator><contains>|<startswith>|<endswith>|[!<>=]+)(?<TestValue>.*?)\)-->(?<Depth>)|<!--@EndIf-->(?<-Depth>))*(?(Depth)(?!))<!--@EndIf-->

Comment: @user1844646 if you want to use stuff like this in your production code, you **need** to use `IgnorePatternWhitespace`, format it like my answer and add in comments. No one will ever be able to make sense of that (even if you are working on the project all by yourself; by Christmas you will have forgotten what this does in detail)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex to retrive the contents of each if block as part of the match group `VALUE`. The outermost match is the last one in the array:

```
(?<=\bif)(?>if(?<DEPTH>)|(?<VALUE-DEPTH>)endif|.?)*(?(DEPTH)(?!))(?=endif\b)
```

Note that for clarity I am using `if` and `endif` to represent your opening and closing syntax.

You could then use this regex on the last value in the group to extract the else clause:

```
(?<=else)((?!else).)+$
```